# How to load a image until a document is loaded into a page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I am developing a website,i need to load a pdf document into a page. i successfully loaded the document in the page by using iframe. But it takes time to load the pdf document, during the loading of that document i need to show an message that the "document is loading" until the pdf document is fully loaded. Can any one please help me to solve this problem by using java script or any other method.

thanks in advance.

Comment: you may try `<iframe onload="document.getElementById('loading').style.display='none'">` if that works we can take it from there

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using this :

```
<script>
  $(function(){
     $("#loader").html(""); 
     // document loaded successfully
   });
</script>

<body>

<div id='loader'> Document is loading.Please wait...</div>

</body>
```

Comment: And how does that go away when the iframe has finished loading a document we cannot access ourselves?

Comment: @mplungjain...one your pdf purely loaded in browser..then ready function get called automatically..

Comment: Not if you load it after the page has loaded, for example with a link

Answer (score 0):

Use a loading gif on the screen you can google that. I personally like  [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-k1SkZQ3EPHA/Ti6wX9Z4oTI/AAAAAAAAAg4/TEtujIAwrEM/s320/spiral.gif).

You can place it in a div that is `absolute` in the centre of the screen with CSS.

This is the html

```
<div id='loading'>
    <h2>Loading document please wait...</h2>
    <img src="yourLoadingGif.gif />
</div>
```

Now for the document, you could use this onload handler to clear the loading gif and display message

```
<iframe onload="document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML=null">
```